# Keytool IOException when trying to convert JKS to PCKS12

Tags: java, keytool, jks

I have a JKS keystore that I want to convert to PCKS12 type, so I can later on export private key from it using openssl.
The problem is, when I run the `keytool` command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass pass -deststorepass pass -srcalias alias -destalias alias -srckeypass pass -destkeypass pass -noprompt
```

I get

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
```

I searched the Net looking for solution, and looks like it already happened to other people, but usually the problem was either in command or in source JKS keystore. Unfortunately, I cannot regenerate source JKS, also I have not other way to verify rather than

```
keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks
```

which returns valid result:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

key, 28.04.2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): ...
```

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there any other way to export private key from JKS?

Thanks